# How do you know if an AP caster should go mana, CDR, AP, or all three?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that some champions are completely dedicated to one of them, such as ryze to mana, however for other champions is it a case by case basis?, based on who they are laning against?, based on player skill, or, of course, based on the champion?

Answer (score 1):

Who you're laning against does not affect what your kit scales with.

Needing CDR is dependent on your abilities and their cooldowns.  Needing AP is dependent on your ratios.  Needing mana is dependent on your mana pool numbers and mana costs.

Your opponent, depending on their playstyle and champion, dictates if you need to build **health or MR**, but not AP/CDR/Mana.  (An exception would be Veigar, where some champions will choose to rush health/MR and hold off on building AP in order to keep from being bursted at level 6 and onwards).

In short, building Mana/CDR/AP is completely dependent on your champion and playstyle.  For example, Anivia players will usually prioritize one of two routes early on:

1. Mana (Tear -> Catalyst/ROA/Deathcap)
2. AP (straight to ROA/Deathcap)

Answer (score 0):

I do it based on the champion.  For example for morgana I go movement speed quints, for champs like ahri and tf I go flat ap quints for easier last hitting. And when I am expected to lose lane I like to rune magic resist red and blues.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your play style.  There are so many different types of AP Champions that can be played so many different ways.  For example I personally play Ahri two ways  Move speed/CDR which is my kiting build and Health/AP which is my jump in the middle of the fight and melt faces build.

Or if you need to counter a talon middle and he hard counters your pick,  you may need to rush an armor item and catalyst just so he isn't able to burst you down at lvl 6.

Please be more specific by maybe asking about a certain champion match up =)?